# Why can't I open a website in the browser even though I can curl on my linux localhost?

Tags: browser, curl, webserver

I can curl the contents of an internally hosted site using curl http://localhost:9000 but cannot connect when I try to open the same in the windows browser http://ip-address:9000/. I am trying to do this from within the internal network.

Comment: Just to confirm - did you literally enter "ip-address:9000"?

Comment: is that the same when you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the address?
have you tried adding a local domain to your hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1 and connecting to that.
Also check for proxy settings in the browser.

Comment: @rob - I am trying to access this from my windows machine browser so used the actual ip address of the linux server hosting the site. I curled it on linux using localhost though. Haven't tried tried "adding a local domain to hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1" will try.

Comment: try curl from windows, I use it from cygwin, might be an iptables/firewall issue no allowing incoming connections. if you have wireshark installed in linux you should be able to see the connection packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin needed to open up iptables port 3000 and then it worked on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the site via curl using `localhost` as the address implies that your machine (the local host) is the one hosting the site.  Then you say that you're on Windows and the site's being served by a linux machine.  Which is it?

Regardless, if you can get the contents via curl using `http://localhost:9000`, then you should be able to get the contents via your web browser using `http://localhost:9000`.  Try that.